# Component props will not update after state if redux state changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, gatsby

So I have read through numerous post which seem to cover the same topic as me, but after trying all their solutions, I simply cant make it work, so here it goes.

I have a simple search filter, that I use to filter some recipes by their name. I have a Redux Store to handle the state(value) of the search filter. When entering values in the input field, my actions goes fine to the reducer, which updates the state (I can see that with both console.logs and Redux DevTools). But somehow, this doesn't update my props, which are mapped with connect and mapStateToProps

All previous answers I have come across, points to mutating state, but I have tried to go over multiple iterations of my reducer, but then again, I might just be overlooking something.

My filter action dispatch:

```
filter(e){
    Store.dispatch({
        type: 'SET_NAME_FILTER',
        payload: e.target.value
    })
}
```

My reducer:

```
const filterNameReducer = (state = [""], action) => {
    if (action.type === 'SET_NAME_FILTER') {
        return [
            action.payload
        ];
    }
    return state;
}
```

My RecipeListContainer:

```
class RecipeListContainer extends React.Component {    
    render() {
        return (
            <RecipeList recipes={ this.props.recipes } filterName={ this.props.filterName }/>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        filterName: state.filterNameState,
    }
}
module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps)(RecipeListContainer)
```

My RecipeList component:

```
class RecipeList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.recipes.filter(this.filters, this).map(({ node: recipe }) => {
                    return (
                        <RecipeListItem key={ recipe.id } id={ recipe.id } value={ 0 } name={ recipe.name } time={ recipe.time } type={ recipe.type } tags={ recipe.tags } ingredients={ recipe.ingredients } />
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
        )
    }
    filters() {
        if (this.props.filterName[0].length != 0) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that my filter doesn't do that much yet, but I've made it simple, so that i just could see if it gets updated. And it filter correct, if i change the initial value of my reducer. So shouldn't be that.

Also, Im using it in a GatsbyJS, but according to their documentation and examples, this should not be a problem. But i could be wrong?

Lots of thanks in advance! If I have missed something for you to find a solution, let me know, Im new to posting on SO.

Comment: `this.props.recipes.filter(this.filters, this` what does this code do?

Comment: can you show your redux state structure?

Comment: Not strictly an answer, but we solved this by putting a `filter` into component state and then filtering the data from `pageQuery` in javascript inside the component. If you want to use more sophisticated state manipulation, then redux is probably worth the effort.